# Why pkill return -9?

Tags: linux, python3, pkill

I want to run command `pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'` in python3 use `subprocess.run`,  but I do not know why `returncode=-9`, can anyone explain this?

```
>>> subprocess.run("pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'", shell=True)
CompletedProcess(args="pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'", returncode=-9)
```

When I run the same command in bash shell, the return code is 0:

```
$ pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'
$ echo $?
0
```

**Run command in bash shell:**

```
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# ps -ef | grep -E 'java.*7104' | grep -v grep
root     127147      1 99 11:37 pts/1    00:00:13 java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx10240m -jar ./aichemy.jar --server.port=7104 --spring.profiles.active=test01_use
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# echo $?
0
```

**Run command use `subprocess.run`:**

```
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# ps -ef | grep -E 'java.*7104' | grep -v grep
root     128644      1 99 11:38 pts/1    00:00:22 java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx10240m -jar ./aichemy.jar --server.port=7104 --spring.profiles.active=test01_use
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Apr 16 2020, 17:47:17) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run("pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'", shell=True)
CompletedProcess(args="pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'", returncode=-9)
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode) says "A negative value `-N` indicates that the child was terminated by signal `N` (POSIX only)." What part of that is unclear?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica When I run  `pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'` in bash shell, the value of `$?` is 0, why run same command use `subprocess.run`, the return code is -9?

Comment: When your Python script runs, do you have a process running that matches `java.*7104`? How about when you do it from bash?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I have update the question

Comment: Post text, not images of text, and especially not animations of text.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I post the gif picture.

Comment: You did the wrong thing, so that's why I said not to do it. Get rid of them and replace them with plain text.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica OK, I have update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `subprocess.run` with `shell=True`, Python starts a shell process that in turn starts your process. This means that it executes `sh -c "pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'"`. The `pkill` process only has special protections to avoid matching itself, not to avoid matching its parent process. You need to adjust your regex to not match itself. Putting a `^` before `java` is probably the easiest way to do that, like this:

```
subprocess.run("pkill -9 -f '^java.*7104'", shell=True)
```